How can i use test creating a page in wagtail with a complex stream field
I have the following page model on my website
class MyPage(Page):
    questions = StreamField(
        [
            (
                "question",
                blocks.StructBlock(
                    [
                        ("question", blocks.CharBlock()),
                        (
                            "answers",
                            blocks.ListBlock(
                                blocks.StructBlock(
                                    [
                                        ("answer", blocks.CharBlock()),
                                        (
                                            "correct",
                                            blocks.BooleanBlock(
                                                required=False, default=False
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    ]
                                ),
                                min_num=2,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
            ),
        ]
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('questions')
    ]

I asked a similar question a few months ago about how to test page creation but now I have a page model which has a more complex structure for the stream field, and I don't know what to put in this case where it is a multilevel block structure. What does the stream_field supposed to look like for questions?
